# Unable to update react state with an array

Tags: reactjs, search, autocomplete

I can make a successful call to `getApiSuggestions` with data returned. However I'm unable to assign this to  my state.

As you can see my console output shows that the value for `response` has an array. However, when attempting to assign it to `wikiResults:response` the array remains empty.

note that this is a modification of [react-search-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-search-autocomplete)

Am I attempting to pass the variables incorrectly?

[image]

### NarrativeSearch.js

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import './search.css'
import { ReactSearchAutocomplete } from 'react-search-autocomplete'
import { getApiSuggestions } from '../../requests/requests';
import {TextSearchContext} from "../../contexts/TextSearchContext"
import {SearchContext} from "../../contexts/SearchContext"



function Search() {
    const {textFilterState, setTextFilterState} = useContext(TextSearchContext);
    const [wikiTitleResults, setWikiTitleResults] = useState({wikiResults:[]});




    var cnJson = wikiTitleResults;

  const items = wikiTitleResults.wikiResults;

    const handleOnSearch = (string, results) => {
        console.log("STRING: ", string)
        getApiSuggestions(string).then(response => {

            console.log("RESPONSE: ", response);
            setWikiTitleResults({wikiResults:response});  //<---- This doesn't update the state
            console.log("WikiTitle: ", wikiTitleResults.wikiResults);
            console.log("Items: ", items);

        })


    }

  const handleOnHover = (result) => {
    // the item hovered
    console.log(result)
  }

  const handleOnSelect = (item) => {
    // the item selected
        setTextFilterState({textFilter:item.name});
    console.log(item)
  }

  const handleOnFocus = () => {
    console.log('Focused')
  }

    const handleOnClear = () => {
    setTextFilterState({textFilter:""});
  }

  const formatResult = (item) => {
        return (
      <>
        <span style={{ display: 'block', textAlign: 'left' }}>id: {item.title}</span>

      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div >

        <div className="searchbar">
                <ReactSearchAutocomplete
                    items={items}
                    onSearch={handleOnSearch}
                    onHover={handleOnHover}
                    onSelect={handleOnSelect}
                    onFocus={handleOnFocus}
                    onClear={handleOnClear}
                    styling={{ zIndex: 4 }} // To display it on top of the search box below
                    autoFocus
                />
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

### getApiSuggesetions

```
const getApiSuggestions = (title) => {
    //console.log("URL Being called"+ urlSingleResult);
    //console.log(title);
    let result = urlMultiResult
        .get(`${title}`)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(Object.values(response.data.query.pages))
            return Object.values(response.data.query.pages);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return error;
            console.log(error);
        });
    console.log(result);
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by including a `useEffect` and a `context` from the parent component.

```
function Search() {
    const {textFilterState, setTextFilterState} = useContext(TextSearchContext);
    const {wikiTitleResults, setWikiTitleResults} = useContext(SearchContext);

    var items = wikiTitleResults.wikiTitles;

    useEffect(() => {
                const fetchData = async () => {
                    const data = await getApiSuggestions(textFilterState.textFilter)
                    setWikiTitleResults({wikiTitles:data})
                }
                fetchData();
                },

             [textFilterState])

    const handleOnSearch = (string, results) => {
        setTextFilterState({textFilter:string});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A re-render is needed in order to have the state updated, it is an asynchronous task. Put this line

```
console.log("WikiTitle: ", wikiTitleResults.wikiResults);
```

outside of `handleOnSearch` somewhere in your component, and you will see it gets updated after the re-render.

Comment: I can confirm that it does indeed populate. How can I force a re-render?

Comment: You can't actually, it is how React is built. And in general you don't needed it. If you wanna do something with the data in `handleOnSearch` use `response` instead of the state.

Comment: The problem here is that I need to make a call to an API to populate the value of the array `items = []`. And the dropdown will only populate if the array is populated _before_ you start searching.

Comment: You should handle the populating process and searching separately. For example populate on mount with `useEffect`,  so that `handleOnSearch` does just the filtering.

Comment: I understand. And that is in agreement with what I was attempting earlier. However, how does one prepopulate the `items` array  with values, by performing the API call, prior to typing in the search box?

Comment: Take a look at my answer please, I just edited it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yep, I understand what's going on here. The useEffect is throwing an error `string is not defined`.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I'm gonna think and see if I get something better.

Comment: Thank you, I very much appreaciate it.